# RStudio Server Initialization Error: TypeError:c is undefined

Tags: typeerror, rstudio-server

When I'm trying to login to **RStudio server**, I see the message

> "RStudio Server Initialization Error" and "TypeError:c is undefined" as in the screenshot.

What does this mean?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do not user the browser attached in RHEL 6. i met the same issue with firefox . it is fixed when i use Chrome .